# How to show that for $Q>1$, $\sum\frac{1}{n}=\frac{\phi(Q)}{Q}\log x + O(1)$, where $n<x$ and $(n,Q)=1$ and where the O constant may depend on $Q$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here $\phi$ denotes the totient function. I can't quite get the solution despite trying to use techniques like inclusion and exclusion principle. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to help you get started. Suppose we treat the case
where $x=m$ and $m$ is a multiple of all primes $p$ that divide $Q.$

Then by inclusion-exclusion we have that the sum is
$$H_m - \sum_{p|Q} \frac{1}{p} H_{m/p}
+ \sum_{p, q|Q} \frac{1}{pq} H_{m/p/q} 
- \sum_{p, q, r|Q} \frac{1}{pqr} H_{m/p/q/r} 
+\ldots $$

Recall that $H_m \sim \log m$ so that the dominant contribution to the
above (keeping  in mind that  the number of  prime divisors of  $Q$ is
finite) is
$$\log m \times
\left(1 - \sum_{p|Q} \frac{1}{p}
+ \sum_{p,q|Q} \frac{1}{pq}
- \sum_{p,q,r|Q} \frac{1}{pqr}
+\ldots\right).$$

This however is clearly
$$\log m \times \prod_{p|Q} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
= \log m \times \frac{\varphi(Q)}{Q}.$$

This of course merely represents the intuitively obvious fact that the
proportion of numbers coprime to $Q$ is $\varphi(Q)/Q.$

We can do  somewhat more and predict the  constant using Mellin-Perron
summation. Observe  that the Euler  product of those numbers  that are
coprime to $Q$ is by inspection given by
$$\zeta(s) \times \prod_{p|Q} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right).$$
Hence the term $1/n$ where $n$ is coprime to $Q$ has Euler product
$$L(s) =
\zeta(s+1) \times \prod_{p|Q} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{s+1}}\right).$$

Denote by $a(n)$ the value $1/n$ if $(n, Q) = 1$ and zero otherwise.
Then by Mellin-Perron
$$\sum_{n\le m} a(n)
= \frac{1}{2} a(m)
+ \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} L(s)\; m^s \frac{ds}{s}.$$

Evaluate this by shifting from the line $\Re(s)=1$ to 
$\Re(s)= -1/4.$

There is a double pole at $s=0$. We have
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(L(s) \; \frac{m^s}{s}; s=0\right)
= \log m + \gamma.$$

This yields for the sum the expression
$$\frac{1}{2} a(m)
+ (\log m + \gamma)\prod_{p|Q} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)
\\ = \log m \times \frac{\varphi(Q)}{Q}
+ \gamma \times \frac{\varphi(Q)}{Q}
+ \frac{1}{2} a(m).$$

The tricky part  in making this rigorous is  to estimate the remainder
integral.

**Remark.** The residue is calculated from the expansions
$$\zeta(s+1) = \frac{1}{s} + \gamma - \gamma_1 s + \ldots$$
and
$$m^s = 1 + (\log m) s + \frac{1}{2} (\log m)^2 s^2 + \ldots.$$

As  we already have  a factor  of $1/s$  in the  integral we  need the
constant term of this product, which is $\log m + \gamma.$

**Addendum.** We can improve this result with a closed form of the constant, which depends on $Q.$It is clear that we get a contribution
of   $$\gamma  \times   \frac{\varphi(Q)}{Q}$$  from   the  asymptotic
expansion of the harmonic numbers.

Note however  that we can also  give a closed form  of the logarithmic
terms that appear.  Let $Q_{\setminus  p}$ be the product of all prime
divisors  of  $Q$  except  $p$   and  ask  about  the  coefficient  on
$\log(p)/p,$ which is

$$1 -  \sum_{q|Q_{\setminus p}} \frac{1}{q}
+ \sum_{q,r|Q_{\setminus p}} \frac{1}{qr}
- \sum_{q,r,s|Q_{\setminus p}} \frac{1}{qrs}
+ \ldots$$
where the summation is understood to range over prime divisors of 
$Q_{\setminus p}$.
This is clearly seen to have the value
$$\frac{\varphi(Q_{\setminus p})}{Q_{\setminus p}}.$$

Therefore the constant is in fact
$$\gamma  \times   \frac{\varphi(Q)}{Q}
+ \sum_{p|Q} \frac{\log p}{p}
\frac{\varphi(Q_{\setminus p})}{Q_{\setminus p}}.$$

We have a case here where the remainder integral from Mellin-Perron contributes to the constant of the asymptotic expansion and hence requires further investigation.